# unique random number generation in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to add a unique random number from 0 - list length in my query it is for a lottery which the random number is associated with the winning number.

The fields I have are player Name (which can have duplicated since they can buy multiple tickets) employee ID (again duplicates) and amount paid.

I have tried RND function : `Random Number: Int(Rnd([Employee ID])*20288)+1`

but I am getting duplicate numbers and when I try sorting in datasheet view  the random numbers update themselves even if I just click on a record it changes.

```
Player Name  Employee ID    Payment Amount  Random Number
Bill Bill      000012          15.00               14756
Name2          000452          20.00               13916
Name2          000452          20.00               9512
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to store the numbers as you generate them, and then check for duplicates by comparing each newly-generated number against the stored ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `RandomRowNumber` found here: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers#4-random-row-numbers) to sort the numbers.

Another extremely simple method is to write the lottery numbers to a (temp) table having a *GUID* or a *random autonumber* (in the table designer, Access calls it a *Replication ID*) as the primary key. Then sort on that and, in a query, select the `Top N` records to get the winning numbers.

Comment: The GUID + Top N method is pretty cool! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
Public Function GetRandomDouble(Optional ByVal iLength As Integer = 3) As Double
    Dim s As String: s = String(iLength, " ")     'fixed length string with 8 characters
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim ch As Integer 'the character
      Randomize
    For n = 1 To Len(s) 'don't hardcode the length twice
        Do
            ch = Rnd() * 127 'This could be more efficient.
            '48 is '0', 57 is '9', 65 is 'A', 90 is 'Z', 97 is 'a', 122 is 'z'.
        Loop While ch < 48 Or ch > 57 'And ch < 65 Or ch > 90 And ch < 97 Or ch > 122
        Mid(s, n, 1) = Chr(ch) 'bit more efficient than concatenation
    Next
  
GetRandomDouble = CDbl(s)
End Function
```

And use it in your query like this

```
Random Number: GetRandomDouble(5)
```